# Only have globalAlpha effect one layer of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to use globalAlpha to 'fade out' the top layer of my canvas, to revel a middle layer image, and a solid background color. I'm using the code below, which successfully fades out the black layer. However, I cannot seem to stop the blue background layer from also fading out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img;    
img = new Image();
img.src = "img/background4x3.png";

var i = 1;
function test1() {

    ctx.fillStyle = "#4DB8FF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 500);


    if (i > 0) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = i;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
        setTimeout(test2, 100);
    }
}

function test2() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    i -= 0.01;
    test1();    

}

img.onload = function () {          
    test1();
    }


   </script>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have tried to use an if and a while statement based on the globalAlpha, but no luck as of yet.

Comment: Canvas's DON'T have layers. They aren't designed to have layers. So, no there is no way to fade out a top layer because it doesn't exist. You can look up EaselJS etc. which simulate `<canvas>` layers in JS but in native JS it CANNOT work

Comment: @cjds Nothing prevent you to use different off-screen canvases, that will act exactly as layers would.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got this right. Image to fade from black while background blue/cyan is not affected.

You need to use the `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` (GCO) and it is a little counter intuitive.

1. First clear the canvas (must be done) so that all pixels are opaque.
2. Set GCO to `source-over` this is the default and draws all pixels
   from the source (thing you are drawing) over all pixels on the
   destination (canvas) apart from transparent pixels of course.
3. Set the `globalAlpha` to the fade level.
4. Then draw the black rectangle.
5. Set the `globalAlpha` back to 1
6. Set GCO to `destination-atop` this means all pixels from the source
   (image) that are not opaque have the destination pixels appear on
   top. Thus only opaque/semi opaque pixels in the image will have the black pixels from the last draw drawn on top
7. Draw the image
8. Set the GCO to `destination-over` this means that all pixels from
   the last draw that are on the canvas (the image with fading black)
   appear over the cyan rectangle that will be drawn. All other pixels will
   get the source pixels (the cyan background)
9. Draw the cyan background rectangle.

All done.

When `fadeIn === 0` the GCO `destination-atop` fails because all pixels are transparent in the black background. So ensure that you draw the images via a second method as demonstrated in the code.

A working example at jsFiddle

[Fiddle of code below](https://jsfiddle.net/blindman67/mj4dvpqk/)

The odd thing is that the code below does not work if inserted as a Stack Overflow Snippet

Code.

```
// set up canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // why? Just habbit;

// create image
var img;    
img = new Image();
var fadeIn = 1;

function update() {
    if(fadeIn <= 0){  // when fade done draw normally
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;  // set alpha
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // default blend mode
        ctx.fillStyle = "#4DB8FF"; // background
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // do it all again in 4 secs.
        setTimeout(function(){
          fadeIn = 1;
          window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }, 4000); // do it again in four seconds
    }else{
        // first draw the black fading out
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";       
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        ctx.globalAlpha = fadeIn;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // now draw the image with destination-atop
        // this means that for each visible pixel (alpha > 0)
        // draw the destination pixels (what is already on the canvas)
        // over the top
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";      
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1; 
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // and last draw the background with destination over.
        // which means only draw pixels where the destination
        // pixels are transparent.
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";      
        ctx.fillStyle = "#4DB8FF";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // decrease fade
        fadeIn -= 0.02;
        // call next frame
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
    }

}

// start it all happening.
img.onload = function () {     
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

// load the image.
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysINC.png";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure this what OP wanted but +1 because well explained and probably helpful for future readers (Ps, I stole your image :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have layers with canvas.

The idea is that each layer will be an off-screen canvas, that you will draw in proper order on the main, on-screen canvas.

Using your code, it would give something like :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img;    
img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysINC.png";
// an array containing our canvases' contexts
var layers = [];
for( var i=0; i<3; i++){
  // we can only save the contexts 
  // since we've got a reference to their canvas in it
  layers.push(canvas.cloneNode(true).getContext('2d'));
  }
// the alpha values for layer2 and layer1
var i = 1;
var k = 1;

function test1() {
    // layer0 is our background
    layers[0].fillStyle = "#4DB8FF";
    layers[0].fillRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    // the middle image
    layers[1].globalAlpha = k;
    layers[1].drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 500);
    if (i > 0) {
        // the top black layer
        layers[2].globalAlpha = i;
        layers[2].fillStyle = "#000000";
        layers[2].fillRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
        setTimeout(test2, 100);
    }
    else{
        test3();
      }
    // draw each of our layers's canvas on the main one
    for(var j=0; j<layers.length; j++){
      ctx.drawImage(layers[j].canvas, 0,0);
      layers[j].clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
}

function test2() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    i -= 0.01;
    test1();    
}
function test3() {
  if(k>0){
    k -= 0.1;
    setTimeout(test2, 100);
    }
  }
img.onload = function () {          
    test1();
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
```

And in case @Blindman67 got correctly what you wanted, you can still use this idea of layers, setting the gCO of only one of your contexts :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img;    
img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysINC.png";
// an array containing our canvases' contexts
var layers = [];
for( var i=0; i<3; i++){
  // we can only save the contexts 
  // since we've got a reference to their canvas in it
  layers.push(canvas.cloneNode(true).getContext('2d'));
  }
// the alpha values for layer2 and layer1
var i = 1;

function test1() {
    // layer0 is our background
    layers[0].fillStyle = "#4DB8FF";
    layers[0].fillRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    // the middle image
    layers[1].drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 500);
    if (i > 0) {
        // the top black layer
        layers[2].globalAlpha = i;
        layers[2].fillStyle = "#000000";
        layers[2].fillRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
        setTimeout(test2, 100);
    }
    // change our image layer's gCO
    layers[1].globalCompositeOperation="source-atop";
    // draw the black layer on it
    layers[1].drawImage(layers[2].canvas, 0,0);
    // reset image layer's gCO
    layers[1].globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
    // draw each of our layers's canvas on the main one
    for(var j=0; j<layers.length; j++){
      // don't draw the black layer since it's already on the image's one
      if(j!==2)
        ctx.drawImage(layers[j].canvas, 0,0);
      layers[j].clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
}

function test2() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    i -= 0.01;
    test1();    
}
img.onload = function () {          
    test1();
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
```